# how to change text color without changing the the whole textview color

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to change the text color by simply clicking the button but when I click the button it changes the previously typed text color also. Means changes the whole text color. When I try to change color through Spannable then it changes the color of the selected part of the text but not for the text which I am going to type next. Is there a way where I can click the button and it does not change the whole text color but the color for which I type next. Thanks

[image]

here is what I know only

```
redtxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
            str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor(txtColor)),     selStart, selEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
               text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#d32f2f"));
       }
   });
```

Comment: Can u explain more about your requirement and also share your whole code like what is `str` and what is `txtColor`

Comment: Spannable str = text.getText();
        int selStart = text.getSelectionStart();
        int selEnd = text.getSelectionEnd();
        ForegroundColorSpan[] styleSpans = text.getText().getSpans(selStart, selEnd, ForegroundColorSpan.class);  and txtColor is the String which is the return value of button click for color.

Comment: and what is `str` here  can u please explain more about the same

Comment: str is Spannable name.

Comment: @SShah , You need to implement **Spannable String builder** and **onChangeText** just **append spanned string** to Spannable String builder.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SpannableString` for example:

```
final SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Hello stackOverflow");
text.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), text.length() - "stackOverflow".length(), text.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 3, text.length() - 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(text);
```

Comment: I dont understand this part text.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), text.length() - "stackOverflow".length(), text.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

Comment: or see some example in this link :https://medium.com/@programmerr47/working-with-spans-in-android-ca4ab1327bc4

Answer (score 0):

get your whole text into **Spannable** like

```
Spannable text = edittext.getText();
```

After that just do.

```
if (edittext.getText().length() != 0){
     text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(YOUR_COLOR), selection_start, selection_end, 34);
}
```

Comment: It partially works but it does not work when I directly go to the next line then text color set to default. And also when I click near other span text it does not get its color from it.

Comment: Then you need to code into TextWatcher() of Edittext. 
Apply above line every onTextChanged().
--->>>>>
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s1, final int start, final int before, final int count) {
                text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), start, start+1, 34);
            }

Comment: Now this works perfectly. Thanks. One more thing how can I get the color of adjacent text?? Let's suppose I typed previously in blue color and now I am typing in red color but when I want to add something in the blue text it takes that blue color from it and starts typing in the blue color in that area?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement **Spannable String builder(Global Object)** and **on onChangeText event** just append spanned string to Spannable String builder.

```
    SpannableStringBuilder objSpannableStringBuilder;

edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
              final SpannableString text = new SpannableString(s.toString());
              text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 3, text.length() - 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);                  objSpannableStringBuilder.append(text);
              your_edit_text.setText(objSpannableStringBuilder);

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: what is meant by "your_edit_text(Spannable String) comes ere" this in your code?

Comment: @SShah It means your text changed string (Variable CahrSequense s). I just edited answer. Check it now